# How to use automapper in dapper interface(IDBConnection) with SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, dapper

```html
public IEnumerable<voucher> index(string word, string DivisionCode, string yearlabel, int pageno)
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                var data = dbConnection.Query<fydates>(@"SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),fystart,6),' ','-') as fystart,
                REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),fyend,6),' ','-') as fyend FROM fydates WHERE yearlabel = @yearlabel",
                new { yearlabel = yearlabel }).Single();

                List<voucher> DataQuery = dbConnection.Query<voucher, accounts, division, LockStatus, voucher>(@"SELECT V.id,V.voucherno,
                CASE WHEN V.vouchertype='P' THEN 'Paid' ELSE 'Receipt' END AS vouchertype,
                REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),V.dated,6),' ','-') AS dated,V.subno,V.amount,COALESCE(V.syscreated,' ') AS syscreated,V.bankcode,
                COALESCE(V.cheqno,' ') AS Cheqno,V.Cheqdate,V.posted,V.currency,A.id as accountsid,A.achead,A.shortname,
                D.id as divisionid,D.divname,D.divncode,L.id as lockstatusid,L.name FROM voucher V
                LEFT JOIN Accounts A ON V.bankcode = A.mainac
                LEFT JOIN divisionmst D ON V.divisionid = D.divncode
                LEFT JOIN LockStatus L ON V.posted=L.Type
                WHERE (V.voucherno + V.Subno+V.cheqno + A.achead + LEFT(yearvoucherno,3) LIKE @word AND
                D.divncode LIKE @DivisionCode) AND (dated BETWEEN @fystart AND @fyend OR dated='31-Mar-49')
                Order By V.id DESC OFFSET @pageno *25 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS only",
                (voucher, accounts, division, LockStatus) =>
                {
                    voucher.accounts = accounts;
                    voucher.division = division;
                    voucher.LockStatus = LockStatus;
                    return voucher;
                },
                new { word = word, fystart = data.fystart, fyend = data.fyend, DivisionCode = DivisionCode, pageno = pageno - 1 },
                splitOn: "accountsid, divisionid, lockstatusid").ToList();
                return DataQuery;
            }
        }
```

In earlier scenario, i have used mapping technique using spliton in JOINS queries, it perfectly worked. But in case of union queries or case when conditions i am stucked as i am not able to decide where should i spliton. As in above mention union and case when condition i am not able to decide where to spliton

Answer (score 0):

Simply add dummy columns to help Dapper know where to split.  Note that if the dummy column is null, the associated object will be null.  Also note that the dummy columns do not need to exist on your target objects.

```
select
--first object
1 AS Id,
(1+1) AS APropertyAssociatedToYourFirstObject,
(1+1) AS ADifferentPropertyAssociatedToYourFirstObject,

--second object (assuming you are splitting on Id)
1 AS Id,
(1+1) AS APropertyAssociatedToYourSecondObject,
(1+1) AS ADifferentPropertyAssociatedToYourSecondObject
from YourTable
```

Also, lining it up like this will save you oodles of time.